# android - parse an xml formatted string into a json array

Tags: android, xml, json, wcf

Lets say I get an xml response from a web method that looks like this:

```
<Response xmlns="http://you.wish.you.knew.com/">
<Result>
[
&#xD;
"IMG_20140210_212703.jpg",
&#xD;
"IMG_20140210_170020.jpg"
&#xD;
]
</Result>
</Response>
```

Im getting this from a wcf webservice that I cant really mess with to much because it will break. How can I take this as a string and extract the data from it so I can turn it into a json array or something that I can turn into a jsonarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1 : Download java-json.jar

2 : Add this to /libs folder of your project then add to build path.

Usage :

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

String testXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" + "<parentNode>"    
+"<test1>1234</test1>"                          
+ "<test2>" + "Test" + "</test2>" 
+ "<test3>" + 120 + "</test3>" 
+ "</parentNode>"; 

JSONObject jsonObj = null;
try {
  jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(testXml);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  Log.e("JSON exception", e.getMessage());
  e.printStackTrace();
} 

Log.d("JSON", jsonObj.toString());
```

Output:

JSON :

{"parentNode":{"test1":1234,"test2":"Test","test3":120}}

Comment: I tried this but it leaves me with garbage symbols in the json. Its the xml mark up symbols like &#xd. How can I properly format the string so it doesnt have all the funky characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

So I didnt want to do a quick and dirty fix as I would like to have implemented some library that would have made a good solid fix that was dependable but all I ended up doing was replacing the '&#xd' characters with '\n' in my string which I was then able to turn into a jsonarray. In the end my solution looks simply like this:

```
JSONObject json = XML.toJSONObject(response);

temp = json.optJSONObject("UploadFileResponse")
.optString("UploadFileResult").toString().replace("&#xd;", "");

return temp;
```

I did end up leaving the library in my project which Gopal had mentioned java-json.jar which I got from online somewhere.